# Url with fragments in bold

Tags: urls, bold, text-decorations

I need to write document containing a lot of URLs but some fragments of these URLs have to be in bold. How can I accomplished this? For urls I use `\nolinkurl` but I can't use `\bf` in it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can select the font used for URL using `\urlstyle`. However bold font isn't supported out-of-the-box. You need to patch the required style definitions as shown below. You need to use a font which supports a bold+text-typer style (expect you want to have the URLs in normal Roman style).

You need to mark the parts of the URL which is different with a different macro. You can define these macros using `\DefineUrlCommand` from the `url` package.
Note that `\url` is defined by the `url` package which is loaded by `hyperref` which then redefines this macro to an hyperlinked version and provides `\nolinkurl` as replacement.

**Update:** I added underline style as now requested. This can be done with the help of the `ulem` package. I also added other fancy URL styles.

**Update 2:**  Simplified code. Added color example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%% works with `url` only as well:
%\usepackage{url}

% Use a font which gives you bold text-typer:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareUrlCommand{\tturl}{\urlstyle{tt}}
\DeclareUrlCommand{\bftturl}{\def\UrlFont{\bfseries}}
\DeclareUrlCommand{\bfurl}{\def\UrlFont{\bfseries\ttfamily}}

% Colors:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareUrlCommand{\redurl}{\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{red}}}

% More fancy URL styles:
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\DeclareFancyUrlCommand[2]{%
    \expandafter\DeclareFancy@UrlCommand
    \expandafter{\csname fancyurl@\expandafter\@gobble\string#2\endcsname}{#1}{#2}%
}
\def\DeclareFancy@UrlCommand#1#2#3{%
    \let#1\empty % must not be \relax
    \useunder{#3}{#1}{}%
    \DeclareUrlCommand{#2}{\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareFancyUrlCommand{\ulurl}{\uline}
\DeclareFancyUrlCommand{\uulurl}{\uuline}
\DeclareFancyUrlCommand{\uwurl}{\uwave}
\DeclareFancyUrlCommand{\sourl}{\sout}
\DeclareFancyUrlCommand{\xourl}{\xout}
\DeclareFancyUrlCommand{\daurl}{\dashuline}
\DeclareFancyUrlCommand{\dourl}{\dotuline}

\begin{document}

\par\bfurl{http://www.example.com/allbold-onlybold}
\par\bftturl{http://www.example.com/allbold-intexttyper}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\bftturl{onlythisisbold}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\ulurl{special$_%part}\tturl{/normal/%$^_/again}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\uulurl{special$_%part}\tturl{/normal/%$^_/again}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\uwurl{special$_%part}\tturl{/normal/%$^_/again}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\sourl{special$_%part}\tturl{/normal/%$^_/again}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\xourl{special$_%part}\tturl{/normal/%$^_/again}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\daurl{special$_%part}\tturl{/normal/%$^_/again}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\dourl{special$_%part}\tturl{/normal/%$^_/again}
\par\tturl{http://www.example.com/}\redurl{special$_%part}\tturl{/normal/%$^_/again}

\end{document}
```

### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: And how can I get underlined parts? Parts in bold are hard to notice when font size is small.

Comment: @jesper: Here you go. For completeness I added other styles as well :-)