# How can I underline a single word with LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, text-decorations

Given a simple paragraph, how do I underline a word in that paragraph?

(Note: I post this here because it wasn't really obvious using google or this site and my TexNicCenter is somehow missing this highlighting option.)

Comment: One reason why it might be missing is that AFAIK underlining is traditionally not used in professional typesetting. Instead italic or bold fonts are used for highlighting. Another alternative would be colored text. In my early LaTeX days I got told to break with this "MS Word habit". Feel free to use it, I just thought it is worth mentioning.

Comment: @M.Scharrer : I want to use it to highlight a part of a textTT formatted source string. Bold/emphasis typeface for textTT doesn't work very well (esp. on-screen).

Comment: The `@` syntax uses the first three characters after it, so `@M.Scharrer` doesn't work. Because out both usernames start the same you need to use at least `@MartinS` (the space can be dropped).

Comment: Related: [Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9550/1235)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` and then `\uline{...}`. It allows line breaks in the underlined text. Other forms of underlining (double, waves) or emphasis (crossed out, ...) are also supported. See the image in [Url with fragments in bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/url-with-fragments-in-bold/12496#12496) for examples.

Comment: When you use \uline the line will be pretty far away from the text but when you use \underline{..} everything will just look fine (this is my personal feeling about it). [Comparison between both (Image 7KB)](https://i.imgur.com/bBT82u3.png)

Comment: @JonasDralle: I guess that `\uline` draws the line at the maximum distance independent of the content while `\underline` directly uses the bounding box of the content. Test it again with content which has a depth, like the word `gym`. Note that `\underline` is AFAIK designed for math and will not break around lines. So it might be fine for single words but not for longer texts.

Comment: @JonasDralle Use a word which has letters such as `g`. See [Comparsion between both (Image, 10kb)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uht0.png). `\uline` is always at the same height, whereas `\underline` on different heights.

Answer (score 54):

Easy enough: `\underline{...}`

Note that this is the simplest form. See the [answer by Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13377/how-can-i-underline-a-single-word-with-latex/13382#13382) for some advanced info.

Comment: The problem with `\underline` is that it doesn't supports line breaks i.e. hyphenation in its content, e.g. like `\mbox` or better `\fbox`. For smaller words this might be ok, but not for longer ones or multiple words.

Answer (score 18):

Beside `\underline` you can also use the packages soul and ulem.

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underline