# underline the doi entry with natbib and abbrvnat style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

is it possible to modify the `abbrvnat.bst` style from the `natbib` package so it underlines automatically the `doi` number in the generated bibliography?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `abbrvnat` bibliography style uses `\doi` for formatting the contents of `doi` fields. It is possible to write a custom definition for `\doi`. The example below also loads `ulem` which defines `\uline` for underlining text. The command [works in some situations where `\underline` fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13382/23160).

[image: Output of the example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}% \uline
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Rutledge19082014,
author = {Rutledge, Robb B. and Skandali, Nikolina and Dayan, Peter and
  Dolan, Raymond J.},
title = {A computational and neural model of momentary subjective well-being},
volume = {111},
number = {33},
pages = {12252--12257},
year = {2014},
doi = {10.1073/pnas.1407535111}, 
journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
}
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{doi: \uline{#1}}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```