# How do you underline

Tags: formatting, text-decorations

How do you underline text?

Also how do you underline math?

Comment: `\underline{}` works for both

Comment: In addition to Null's answer, you can use `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` with `\uline{YourText}` which allows line breaks as well. Or you can avoid underlining altogether as it is not very elegant solution for emphasizing!

Comment: Your question is a little bit unspecific. And why tag `latex-project`?  BTW: underlining is in my opinion not a good typography. Better use italic.

Comment: We don't underline text (it's not a joke).

Comment: Some journals I have submitted to require underlining instead of italics ... The question is legit (although (s)he could easily have found the answer by googling).

Comment: Underlining mathematics is worse than underlining text, because there is a chance that it might confuse the reader. Underlining text makes the text stick out too much, and simultaneously makes the page messier; stick with \emph{xxx} to emphasize text, please.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I guess some use underlining to denote vectors. (Not saying it is good notation, but emphasis is not the only reason for using it.) user1531503: Could your question be considered a duplicate of [How can I underline a single word with LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13377)

Comment: @Sverre Journals are responsible for much evil!

Comment: I recommend the package [ulem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/), as it allows your underlines to break over line ends.

Answer (score 3):

Preface: You should really consider to use macros like `\emph` for emphasizing text. Underlining is from the typewriter-era and is not necessary anymore.

You have some options:

- the macro `\underline` which is pretty inflexible
- the package `ulem` (best to load with `normalem` option) and its macro `\uline` (supports linebreak)
- the package `soul` and its `\ul`