# Crossing out sentences

Tags: text-decorations, strikeout

I had to cross out a sentence and I did it the following way, which is kinda sloppy.

```
$ \rlap{\textbf{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}%
{\mbox{Its derivative should be}}$ $2z + 2\bar{z} =4Re[z]$ So are its critical points all over the real axis?
```

is there a better way to do this and get the same result?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use the either the [`ulem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package or the [`soul`](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % either use this (simple) or
\usepackage{soul} % use this (many fancier options)
\begin{document}

% ulem command
\sout{Its derivative should be $2z + 2\bar{z} =4Re[z]$ So are its critical points all over the real axis?} 

% soul command
\st{Its derivative should be $2z + 2\bar{z} =4Re[z]$ So are its critical points all over the real axis?} 
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1 for `ulem`. It also provides `\xout` to put `XXX` over the text (see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/url-with-fragments-in-bold/12496#12496) for an image.) and allows you to design your own pattern. (`soul` might be able to to the same and more, but I don't know it)

Comment: Note that `ulem` changes the behavior of `emph`. In order to avoid it, add `\normalem` to the preamble after the package insertion.

Comment: That's why I added `[normalem]` as a package option in the example document.  That has the same effect as adding `\normalem` into the preamble.

Comment: I tried both solutions, and my preference goes to `ulem` because its `\sout` command can handle "special" characters (such as é, è, à, ...) commonly used in some languages, whereas `\st` fails.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre Interesting observation, I'd never noticed that.  `soul` will work with accented characters if you are using LuaTeX or XeTeX, though.

Comment: I'm having troubles with ulem and soul when there are references being marked. Does anyone else also experiences this?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão I'm not quite clear what you mean. If the problem is that things you want in italics are showing up underlined instead, make sure you load `ulem` with the `[normalem]`  option. If that's not the problem, maybe you should post a minimal example as a new question.

Comment: For me, with the `ulem` package, the `\sout` command does not wordwrap, which is very annoying. The `soul` package works fully.

Comment: @AlanMunn, `\sout`, `\xout` and `\uwave`not work very well with the environment `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` and `\begin{align}...\end{align}`. Can you please know how to fix it?

Comment: @Achaire `soul` is not really designed for math mode. Depending on what you are trying to do, there are different solutions. See [Color underline a formula](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/9466) and [Overstriking into equation with Soul](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/380921).

Answer (score 30):

You can also use PDF annotations with the [pdfcomment](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pdfcomment.html) package. Then you can also add a comment/note.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=StrikeOut,color=red,author=Approximist]{Its derivative should be $2z + 2\bar{z} =4Re[z]$ So are its critical points all over the real axis?}{comment}
\end{document}
```

[image: \pdfmarkupcomment example]

Comment: Looks nice, but it only works under Adobe Reader, right? And thus not under any Linux distribution. Or is there some way to make the comment show up in a pdf reader in Linux?

Comment: It works with every viewer that implements PDF! OTOH, there are viewers, which promise to be PDF viewers, ... Sorry, but i've lost passion and interest to be up to date with this mess

Comment: I understand that can be quite a hassle. I can tell you that Evince does not seem not show the 'comment box', but Okular does, under Ubuntu 14.10 at least ;).