# Strikethrough text

Tags: strikeout, text-decorations

I am writing an article in LaTeX 2e. Part of the article describes the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and I want to show examples of how multiples of a prime are removed from the sieve by showing them in a strikethrough font. How do I create a strikethrough font in LaTeX 2e?

Comment: Very much related: [Crossing out sentences](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13696/crossing-out-sentences)

Comment: For showing the [Sieve of Eratosthenes in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44673/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-tikz/44682#44682) this might be useful.

Comment: [This](https://jansoehlke.com/2010/06/strikethrough-in-latex/) is the best resource for strikethrough text

Comment: Related question for using \st{} with accented letters: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160220/french-accents-in-hl-from-soul-package

Answer (score 531, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean with creating a strikethrough font.  However, for striking through text horizontally see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663944/how-to-strike-out-inside-latex-equations

So with the [`ulem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package this is:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\sout{Hello World}
```

With the [`soul`](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul) package this is:

```
\usepackage{soul}
\st{Hello World}
```

[image]

The `ulem` package seems more up to date so I would use that.

Comment: Soul is not available on my machine.  I tried ulem.  It worked, producing strikethrough text, but also converted emphasized text from italic to underline, which I do not want. So I added a \normalem declaration, and now everything works properly.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify on the above comment- using the command "\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}" will prevent \emph from being changed, as stated in Section 1 of the documentation (http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.pdf)

Comment: Strangely enough soul seems to have trouble with non-ASCII characters (for instance UTF-8 French).

Comment: The `ulem` package has the highly undesirable side-effect of redefining `\emph{}` to produce underlined text, rather than italic. (I guess "ulem" stands for something like "underlined emph".)

Comment: This didn't work for me... `\sout{}` is just underlining the text.

Comment: @tiktak: indeed, my workaround was to replace e.g. é with \'e

Comment: I am amazed you need an extra package for such a basic function.

Comment: @MichaelChirico happened for me, too, until I noticed, that I used \sout in between dollar signs. Once removed, the underline changed to a proper strikethrough.

Comment: The `ulem` package no longer seems to be more up-to-date than `soul`. `ulem` was last updated in 2019. `soul` was last updated in 2023. Also, for what it's worth, `soul` is on the approved list for the ACM Publishing System (TAPS) and `ulem` isn't.

Answer (score 66):

There is also the [cancel](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) package:

```
\usepackage{cancel}
...
\cancel{text}
```

The solution to [Diagonal strikeout starting too low and ending too high](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high) is another option to consider.

Comment: Is it possible to do strikeout without importing a package?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: Well a package is just a set of macros, so if you define the necessary macros then you don't need to import the complete package. I'd suggest you post a separate question as some others who are more familiar with Plain TeX can probably do a much better job.

Comment: I am amazed you need an extra package for such a basic function.

Comment: `\cancel{}` fails with an error message: "! You can't use `\/' in vertical mode.". `\st{}` functions with the same inputs. I work with pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)

Comment: @LuísdeSousa: I suggest you port a new question with a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that duplicates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: I use $\cancel{x}$ with \usepackage{cancel} but it showed me error which is "! LaTeX Error: File `cancel.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)"

help please. BTW i am using documentclass

Comment: @RIPANDAS: That error means that the package is missing. I suggest you update your packages. If you don't want to do that and only install the `cancel` package.

Answer (score 31):

This is for within an equation (I got it off of another forum) and requires `amsmath` and [`ulem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ulem) to be active. The strike is quite long, so using it next to an arrow is troublesome.

```
\text{\sout{$TEXT$}}
```

Comment: And to make it work properly in math environment, use `\text{\sout{\ensuremath{...}}}`, which may be what you meant by `$TEXT$`. [Reference](http://kheyali.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/how-to-use-strikeoutstrikethrough-font.html).

Comment: This was very helpful. It works on my Texmaker. Thanks. Do you know how to make such a thing work for Math Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Nikos You can use `~` between the text you want to strikeout, or `\cancel` when striking out equations.