# Is there a nice way to make a strikethrough for the square subset character in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, characters, strikeout

I am working on some math that uses the square subset notation. I need a good way to strikethrough the character in LaTeX.

I have tried using the package "cancel" but the strikethrough it produces for the squaresubset character is ugly and looks out of place relative to ⊈ which looks quite nice.

Comment: Check the answers to this question: [How to look up a math symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/2693). There are plenty of versions of the symbol you want in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List.

Comment: Does [this question on strikethrough text help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text/23715#23715)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prefix most mathematical symbols with `\not` in order to negate them. The following looks good according to me:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
Did you know that $\mathcal{A}\sqsubseteq\mathcal{B}$? However, $\mathcal{A}\not\sqsubseteq\mathcal{C}$. Also, $\mathcal{C}\not\subseteq\mathcal{D}$.
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[image: square subset notation]

Alternatively, as suggested by @Alan, there are some variants to this (as well as complete symbols) as part of `txfonts`/`pxfonts`, `mathabx` and `mnsymbol` packages. See the page 37 of Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Actually I think that looks perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that I mention *most mathematical symbols*. That is, you may find some symbols (perhaps very size dependent) do not have a 'perfect' look when negating them with `\not`.