# French accents in \hl from soul package

Tags: unicode, accents, input-encodings, french, soul

I'd like to use the `\hl` command from the soul package in a French text. However, it does not work whenever the part to highlight contains French accents (e.g.: `\hl{é}`).

I could use `\'e` instead of `é` (`\hl{\'e}`) but it would be quite long to substitute all the accents just in case I will have to highlight them later (and there are several accents in French : é, è, ù, à, ...).

Do you know whether it's possible to make `\hl` works with accents without substituing all the accents?

Here is an example file:

```
\documentclass[15pt , a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{y}{RGB}{245, 255, 189}
\sethlcolor{y}

\begin{document}
  \hl{\'e} % works
  %\hl{é} % doesn't work
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Be more specific.

Comment: It returns : "ERROR: Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets has an extra }."

With the package soulutf8 it works.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For UTF-8 input, use `soulutf8`; don't forget `fontenc`!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{y}{RGB}{245, 255, 189}
\sethlcolor{y}

\begin{document}

\hl{\'e}
\hl{é}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is no `15pt` option for `article`.

Comment: Indeed, why do have soul and soulutf8 packages? Madness!

Comment: You could use the `extsizes` package and then use `\documentclass[15pt]{extarticle}`. I don't know about other compilers, but this is just fine in `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: @Someone Yes, if one wants 15pt (there are some reasons one might want to), then `extsizes` is the proper way. My comment was about the OP's document.

Answer (score 7):

use `xelatex` instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt , a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{y}{RGB}{245, 255, 19}
\sethlcolor{y}

\begin{document}
  \hl{\'e} % works
  \hl{é} % works
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `soul` package has its limitations. This one seems to be one of them.

You can let it work by putting accented characters in a `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{y}{RGB}{245, 255, 189}
\sethlcolor{y}

\begin{document}
  \hl{\'e} % works
  \hl{\mbox{é}} % works as well
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Otherwise you have to use XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{y}{RGB}{245, 255, 189}
\sethlcolor{y}

\begin{document}
  \hl{\'e} % works
  \hl{é} % works as well
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to mention that the mbox trick also works for other delicate commands, such as \ce{...}.

Comment: Oh, yes, it also works for \cite !

Comment: @VincentFourmond Happy that my answer helped you!

Comment: `xcolor` works better