# Highlighting words with special characters using \hl (soul)

Tags: xetex, unicode, highlighting, accents, soul

I am using `xelatex`, `polyglossia` and the document is in UTF-8 encoding. I use the `soul` package to highlight words (using `soulutf8` makes no difference).

The problem is really weird, so I will go directly to the minimal (non)working example.

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = sl_SI
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{slovenian}
\usepackage{xcolor,soulutf8}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

% 'č'
Močan: ''\hl{Močan}'' \\
Moč: ''\hl{Moč}'' \\
č: ''\hl{č}'' \\

% 'š'
Pošta: ''\hl{Pošta}'' \\
Tuš: ''\hl{Tuš}'' \\
š: ''\hl{š}'' \\

% 'ž'
Križanec: ''\hl{Križanec}'' \\
Križ: ''\hl{Križ}'' \\
ž: ''\hl{ž}'' \\

\end{document}
```

The document is rendered like this:

[image]

As you can see, I am testing three special characters (čšž). Each of the character is displayed correctly *only* when it is in the middle of the word. It if is in the beggining or at the end, it is not displayed at all.

I have tried using suggestions from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160220/french-accents-in-hl-from-soul-package) post, but couldn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: A tip for you (avoiding use of the `soul` package): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the words in \mbox ? It really should work, from my experience...

Comment: Confirmed that wrapping with \mbox works fine.