# How to yellow highlight differences of two tex documents automatically in LaTex

Tags: highlighting, latexdiff

I want to compare two different tex files, say old.tex and new.tex, by just yellow highlighting the different places in the new.tex automatically.

I tried two ways but not exactly what I want.

1. Use package `soul` and command `\hl` in new.tex. This is ok but it is a manual process and very time-consuming.
2. Run `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex` in the PowerShell, and then compile diff.tex in LaTex. This is automatical, but would highlight the diffrent places in both old.tex and new.tex (contain delete and add notations). Besides, it is not yellow highlight.

Really hope someone can help me, thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's suppose you have these two files, respectively `old.tex` and `new.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    This is the old document.

    This an old line.

    We will remove this line.
\end{document}
```

and

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    This is the new document.

    Esta es una nueva línea.
\end{document}
```

If you run `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > differences.tex` you will have a file which once compiled gives you:

[image]

Ok, now open the new file. Around the beginning of it, you'll find:

```latex
 %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
```

The two commands that mark the "new" text and the "deleted" text are `\DIFadd` and `\DIFdel`. Change them to this:

```latex
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\hl{#1}}} %highlight
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{}                  %do not show deleted
```

Then compile it, you'll have:

[image]

Notice a couple of things:

1. I use `soulutf8` because of this: [French accents in \hl from soul package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160220/french-accents-in-hl-from-soul-package)
2. `latexdiff` has a very complex task to do, and it's not 100% reliable or easy to use; but in plain things it works quite well.
3. I have no idea on how `\hl` will work on large texts or figure or paragraphs...

Comment: Note that If you need to do this repeatedly you can bypass the manual edit by using the --preamble option of latexdiff.  Copying all the commands inserted by latexdiff into a separate file, make the change suggested by @Rmano and then include through the --preamble option

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It is skipping after converting pdflatex, please help.

Comment: @HQuser --- I can't understand your comment, sorry. If you have a problem, please prepare a new question with a complete and simple example (similar to the ones I posted here). Then, if you want, you can add a comment here so that I will see the new question.

Comment: soulutf8 was a very handy suggestion, there are a couple cases it throws errors:
- when DIFadd{} includes \ref or \textsubscript
- in the equation environment
I did not mind manually edit them out, it does ok even with a very complex document.