# Strikethrough command that affects all following text, like \bfseries

Tags: text-decorations, strikeout

Q&As like [Strikethrough text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text), provide guidance on how to strike through text with `ulem`'s `\sout{...}` or `soul`'s `\st{...}`. Is there a readymade alternative that behaves like `\bfseries` and affects all that follows, as opposed to only the provided argument?

In particular I'm looking for something that can be used in combination with this: [Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold)

Solutions working in XeTeX or pdfTeX are equally welcome.

Comment: If you have a font with a struck-through style, you could define a command along the lines of `\bfseries` to switch to that style. Otherwise, there is simply no comparison between what something like `soul` does to construct struck-through text and what font switching commands such as `\bfseries` do. `soul` *reconstructs* the argument passed to `\st{}` with strike-through. If it goes wrong, it tells you that `reconstruction failed`. If Xe/LuaTeX are options, maybe something is possible there, but I kind of doubt it is possible with (pdf)TeX. (You don't say which engine you use.)

Comment: Ah, okay. I wasn't fully aware that \bfseries works through the font-style, while \textbf doens't. Thank you.
XeTeX and pdfTeX are equally fine. Will add that.

Comment: `\textbf{}` just applies `\bfseries` to its argument, so it still works through the font style. But `\st{}` has to do something completely different. If it were just applying e.g. `\ststyle` to its argument, then you could just use that. But it has to do something else because fonts do not (mostly, anyway) provide a struck-through version in the way that they (often) provide a bold variant.

Answer (score 4):

With lualatex and the new lua-ul package you can define commands that works as switches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\newunderlinetype\beginStrikeThough{\leaders\hbox{%
   \normalfont\bfseries/}}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1] {\beginStrikeThough \kant[1-5]}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]