# Make whole line of a table stroke through

Tags: tables, text-decorations

Related to [Make first row of table all bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/make-first-row-of-table-all-bold), however the solution seems not to be transferable to striking text through (see [Strikethrough command that affects all following text, like \bfseries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262021/strikethrough-command-that-affects-all-following-text-like-bfseries)).

So far my solution works by overlaying the respective line with

```
\renewcommand{\sttableline}{\rlap{\rule[3pt]{1\paperwidth}{.4pt}}}
```

through a command in the spirit of my first referenced Q&A above. This is however very unflexible and needs manual adjustment depending on how the respective table is scaled/placed on the page.

**Edit**: Idealy the solution I'm looking for would work withou any modification in the last columns and only need modification of the table header and entries in the first columns.

Comment: The two solution that were already provided answer my original question. However what I am looking for is slightly different. So I've added that I'd prefer a solution that works without modifying adding (something inside) an additional last column. The reason is that the table content is generated by another software.

Answer (score 5):

While someone else provides a better answer, you can always use a [`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
a & a & a \\
\tikzmark{start}b & b & b\tikzmark{end} \\
c & c & c \\
\end{tabular}

\tikz[remember picture] \draw[overlay] ([yshift=.35em]pic cs:start) -- ([yshift=.35em]pic cs:end);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be workable.  There is a slight difference in approach from the cited answer of the OP.  That is, a phantom column must be added at the end of the row (the added space of it is compensated for with a `@{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}` as is shown in my MWE with an `\fbox` around the tabular).

An alternative to the phantom column is to add `\relax` prior to `\\` at the end of each tab row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\relax\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces%
}
\def\mystyle#1\relax{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\rule[2pt]{\wd0}{1pt}\kern-\wd0#1}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r^c@{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}}
\rowstyle{\mystyle}
This is an entry & another entry & a third entry&\\
b & b & b &\\
\rowstyle{\mystyle}
data & other data & last data &\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternate way to achieve the same thing, requiring a little less typing in the `tabular` itself, is to define the `!` column type

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\relax\currentrowstyle}}
\newcolumntype{!}{>{\relax\hspace*{-2\tabcolsep}}c}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces%
}
\def\mystyle#1\relax{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\rule[2pt]{\wd0}{1pt}\kern-\wd0#1}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{$l^c^r!}
\rowstyle{\mystyle}
This is an entry & another entry & a third entry&\\
b & b & b &\\
\rowstyle{\mystyle}
data & other data & last data &\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `pst-node`. I used the `\psDefBoxNodes`, which puts its contents in a box and defines a series  of nodes in that box (12 nodes in all), then I connected a node from the first element in the row to a node from the last element in the row:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    a & a & a \\
    \psDefBoxNodes{B1}{b} & b & \psDefBoxNodes{B2}{b} \\
    c & c & c \\
  \end{tabular}
  \ncline[nodesep=-2pt, offset=-0.3ex, linewidth=0.4pt, linecolor=IndianRed3]{B1: Cl}{B2: Cr}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but adds PGF/Tikz nodes under the rows, columns and cells. It's possible to use those nodes in the so-called `\CodeAfter` to draw with Tikz whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
  \toprule
  Sandra & Alexandra & Anne \\
  Luc & Claude & Jean \\
  Paul & Pierre & Jacques \\
  Laurence & Sophie & Lucie \\
  \bottomrule
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (3.5-|1) -- (3.5-|last) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you prefer a syntax with a command `\Strike` in the beginning of the row to strike, it's also possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Strike}{}
  {
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl 
      { \shess_strike:n { \arabic { iRow } } }
    \ignorespaces
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \shess_strike:n 
  { \tikz \draw (#1.5-|1) -- (#1.5-|last) ; }
 \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
  \toprule
  Sandra & Alexandra & Anne \\
  \Strike Luc & Claude & Jean \\
  Paul & Pierre & Jacques \\
  Laurence & Sophie & Lucie \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

`\g_nicematrix_code_after_tl` is a parameter of `nicematrix`, internal but public, which corresponds to the so-called `\CodeAfter`.

[image: Output of the second code]