# Warning: layout scale set to 0.5 on input line

Tags: warnings

When I compile my dissertation, I have the warning:

> ./thesis.tex:54: Layout scale set to 0.5 on input line 54.

Line 54 contains `\begin{document}`.

The root project file `thesis.tex`, even just the preamble part before line 54, is way too long to post a MWE here.  Does anyone know if there is a common cause of this warning, what it means and what I should be aware of if I ignore it?

---

**Edit**: someone wanted the MWE anyway, so here it goes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath} %Never write a paper without using amsmath for its many new commands 
\usepackage{amssymb} %Some extra symbols 
%\usepackage{makeidx} %If you want to generate an index, automatically 
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} %use [draft] to not paint images for way faster compile times
\usepackage{caption} %If you want to include postscript graphics 
\usepackage{microtype, times, xcolor, lipsum, inputenc} %fancy quote (in mystyle.sty) package dependencies
%\usepackage{mystyle} %Create your own file, mystyle.sty where you put all your own \newcommand statements, for example. 
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{units}%for text like 1/2
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %strikeout text, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text#23712
\usepackage{siunitx} %usage \SI{50}{\milli\kelvin} ==> 50 mK
\usepackage{csquotes} %makes quoted paragraphs have proper indentations with \begin{displayquote}
\usepackage{layouts} %to show margin sizes
\usepackage{setspace} %doublespacing
\usepackage{subfig}

%TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %quick drawing TikZ graphs
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} %suppress TikZ warning

\begin{document} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to post a MWE. Just provide the very minimum to reproduce your problem. If you think it’s too long, do it anyway.

Comment: @Zoxume, Done.  When I compile I get `./mwe.tex:32: Layout scale set to 0.5 on input line 32.`, which is the `\begin{document}` line.

Comment: I meant that you should remove the unnecessary code in your preamble as well, including package inclusions (e.g. I strongly doubt that the url package is the source of the warning). [Go here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/71711) to learn more about MWE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) from your preamble. It's typically used during document design processes, and not as part of your actual document setting.

If you want to see the text block frame, you can use the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) or add the `showframe` option when using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Comment: I'm using layouts to do unit conversions from pts to cm, as in `The text width is \the\textwidth{} or \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\textwidth}.`. Is there a way to do this without `layouts`, or a way to use `layouts` without the warning? The warning is annoying.

Comment: @EL_DON: Use the [`printlen` package](//ctan.org/pkg/printlen).

Answer (score 2):

It just informs you that the pictures drawn by the layouts package will be at  scale 1:2. This is the default value and you can change it if you like. See section 1.2.1 of the package documentation.