# strikethrough math formula in the math mode

Tags: math-mode, strikeout

Is there a way to do strikethrough math formula in the math mode?

I had known this:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\sout{ ...}
```

and

```
\usepackage{soul}
\st{...}
```

are useful but they can not be used in the math mode. So one needs to turn it to the \text mode then do it. Is there any better way out?

I also know this:

```
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\cancel{}
\cancelto{}
```

but they do not look like the strikethrough lines.

Thanks! See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text).

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started.  Note, this does not strike out each component individually; you have to do that yourself.

The `\bgroup` ... `\egroup` serves two purposes.  First is preserves the contents of `\box0`.  It also means you can use `\mathsout` as an exponent etc. without having to enclose it in braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\mathsout}[1]% will draw line through middle of #1
{\bgroup\mathchoice
  {\sbox0{$\displaystyle{#1}$}%
    \usebox0\hspace{-\wd0}%
    \rule[0.5\ht0-0.5\dp0-.5pt]{\wd0}{1pt}}%
  {\sbox0{$\textstyle{#1}$}%
    \usebox0\hspace{-\wd0}%
    \rule[0.5\ht0-0.5\dp0-.5pt]{\wd0}{1pt}}%
  {\sbox0{$\scriptstyle{#1}$}%
    \usebox0\hspace{-\wd0}%
    \rule[0.5\ht0-0.5\dp0-.5pt]{\wd0}{1pt}}%
  {\sbox0{$\scriptscriptstyle{#1}$}%
    \usebox0\hspace{-\wd0}%
    \rule[0.5\ht0-0.5\dp0-.5pt]{\wd0}{1pt}}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x= \cos(\omega t) + \mathsout{sin(\omega t)} + \mathsout{e}^\mathsout{-t}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]