# How should I collaboratively edit a document on ShareLaTeX?

Tags: sharelatex, online, collaboration

I've just been invited to collaboratively author a document on ShareLaTeX, for the first time. Now, in word processors or online collaborative web document editors, there's specific interface for making identifed edits and comments, while on ShareLaTeX I don't quite see this. What I do so far:

- Have a custom inline-comment command with my initials, a different font and a different color so it's clearly identifiable when typesetting.
- Striking out deletions using `\sout` and the `ulem` package, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text).

Can I do better?

Comment: Is this question about Sharelatex or LaTeX?

Comment: Why not using overleaf?

Comment: According to https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2014/03/31/track-changes-in-your-latex-documents.html (from 2014), the features you describe are implemented.

Comment: @Johannes_B: "about ShareLaTeX or LaTeX" - I'm not sure... could be either, I guess. "Why not use overleaf?" 1. Not my choice and 2. The two are merging soon.

Comment: @Johannes_B Since OL and SL are joining, that is of little consequence.
@einpoklum you could use `todonotes` or `fixme` package and leave notes. then compile a list of todos/fixmes and have that at the top of the document. also if you are to use overleaf: see chapter Collaborative Authoring in this: https://www.overleaf.com/articles/collaborative-writing-and-publishing-with-latex-on-overleaf/csxvkcjbsyqg
For Collab Authoring in SL see: https://www.sharelatex.com/track-changes-and-comments-in-latex

Comment: @naphaneal i know. Overleaf has the new interface available.

Answer (score 1):

ShareLatex and the such are bad for you...

As LaTeX is some sort of basic code programming (instead of Word I intend) a great way to collaborate around it is some Gitlab/Github.

That way :

- Your source code get versioning which is amazing.
- You're still owner of your code.
- Each collaborator can locally use his favorite IDE (as a SublimeText enthusiast, anything that has some sort of GUI is very unconfortable to me nowadays, but it's not the same thing for other people)

A sort of quickstart is here : https://medium.com/@rvprasad/a-git-workflow-for-writing-papers-in-latex-4cfb31be4b06