# crossing out using different colour

Tags: color, text-decorations, strikeout

How to cross out a sentence using a horizontal line in a colour different from the text?

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13696/crossing-out-sentences) useful question about how to cross out a sentence, but I cannot figure out how to use colour with this solution. The cancel package allows that, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105902/cancel-with-different-colors), but would not do a horizontal line.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

The second answer in that thread is a working example.

If you want to change the color when using the `soul` package you can use the command `\setstcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setstcolor{red}

\st{Some overstruck text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `ulem` package does not support coloring directly, but looking at its manual, you can find that it is possible to define a new command like

```
\newcommand\redsout{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
```

so that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\redsout{\bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}

\redsout{Some overstruck text}

\end{document}
```

produces the same result as the above one.

Comment: With the ulem-version, I actually get the line behind the text.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Just like the `soul` version shown above.  Maybe the example should call it "understruck" text.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker It works fine for me.