# How to strike through or cancel using different colors in the same line

Tags: math-mode, color, cancel, strikeout

For example, suppose I had an equation

x = 2 + 1 - 2 - 1 (obviously toy example)

I want the +2 to cancel out with the -2, +1 to cancel out with the -1

So in Latex I would want something like

[image]

Is there a simple way to implement multi-colored strike through or cancel in Latex?

[image]

A similar question is found here but it is for global coloring
[crossing out using different colour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/crossing-out-using-different-colour)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is to use `cancel`. (**EDIT**: Replaced `\textcolor` by color, big thanks to Werner!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,xcolor}
\newcommand{\Cancel}[2][black]{{\color{#1}\cancel{\color{black}#2}}}
\begin{document}
\[x~=~\Cancel[blue]{2}+\Cancel[red]{1}-
 \Cancel[blue]{2}-\Cancel[red]{1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that an ambient color will be without effect, i.e. instead of `{\color{green}\Cancel[blue]{2}+\Cancel[red]{1}}` you'd need to do `\Cancel[blue]{\color{green} 2}+\Cancel[red]{\color{green} 1}` unfortunately. I guess that there will be better ways and am looking forward to learn new tricks.

**EDIT**: Just for fun: a Ti*k*Z version. The option `X` will do an `\xcancel` sort of cross out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifCancelX
\tikzset{X/.code={\CancelXtrue}}
\newcommand{\Cancel}[2][]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base),inner sep=0pt] {\node (X) {$#2$};
  \tikzset{#1}
  \draw[#1,overlay,shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt] (X.south west) -- (X.north east);
  \ifCancelX
    \draw[#1,overlay,shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt] (X.north west) -- (X.south east);   
  \fi}
\else
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base),inner sep=0pt] {\node (X) {#2};
  \tikzset{#1}
  \draw[#1,overlay,shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt] (X.south west) -- (X.north east);
  \ifCancelX
    \draw[#1,overlay,shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-2pt] (X.north west) -- (X.south east);
  \fi}%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\[x~=~\Cancel[blue,X]{2}+\Cancel[red]{\frac{1}{2}}-
 \Cancel[blue]{2}-\Cancel[red, line width=1pt]{\frac{1}{2}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I never knew you could use color with cancel ...

Comment: @EnlightenedOne both start with `c` ... ;-) (Note that of course an ambient color will be without effect, i.e. instead of `\textcolor{green}{\Cancel[blue]{2}+\Cancel[red]{1}` you'd need to do `\Cancel[blue]{\textcolor{green}{2}}+\Cancel[red]{\textcolor{green}{1}}` unfortunately. )

Comment: Don't use `\textcolor{<color>}{<stuff>}`, rather use `{\color{<color}<stuff>}`. This translates your implementation to work within math *and* text mode, rather than currently just in text mode. Try with `\Cancel[blue]{\frac{1}{2}}`...

Comment: @Werner Thank you! I did not know that. Do you want to post an answer and I delete mine?

Comment: @marmot Is there a trick to give choice within cancel and xcancel? Otherwise adding a new command Xcancel coded withe \xcancel.

Comment: @pzorba75 I added a Ti*k*Z version that accepts an `X` in the options. I don't know to do it otherwise in one command. Of course, your suggestion works and is much more minimal than loading Ti*k*Z.