# I cannot get a (properly) underlined hyperlink in blue

Tags: hyperref, links, package-options

First I just ignored the *hyperref* package and just wanted something that 'looked' like a link:

```
\underline{\color{Blue} http://soundcloud.com}
```

but I end up getting an underline about 3mm below the link, which looks extremely ugly. After loading *hyperref*, I messed about with the variables but there is no underline feature. The best I could do was get it in blue:

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue}
\urlstyle{same}
\url{http://soundcloud.com}
```

**Question**: Can I get a blue, underlined link so that the line is directly underneath the text (with or without an actual hotlink)?

Comment: I think my answer to [Url with fragments in bold](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/url-with-fragments-in-bold/12496#12496) should answer that. I also show underlined and colored URLs there (but not both in combination yet).

Comment: Note that `\underline` is AFAIK thought for mathematic expressions only, which might explain the odd look for "normal" text. To underline text see the `soul` or `ulem` packages.

Comment: The (under)line is moved down because of the fact that the characters stretch below the baseline. If you want a tighter underline, `\smash` the argument: `\underline{\color{Blue}\smash{http://soundcloud.com}}`. Does this work?

Comment: Here, you can access the documentation for the `ulem` package:
http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.pdf

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't use `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{url}

\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl{%
  \renewcommand\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{blue}}%
  \renewcommand\UrlLeft{\uline\bgroup}%
  \renewcommand\UrlRight{\egroup}}

\begin{document}

\ULurl{http://foo.bar/%12%34}

\end{document}
```

If you use `hyperref`, you may want to click on the URLs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue}
%% or
% \hypersetup{colorlinks=false,pdfborder=000}

% hack into hyperref
\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{%
  \def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{blue}}%
  \def\UrlLeft{\uline\bgroup}%
  \def\UrlRight{\egroup}}
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\hyper@normalise\ULurl@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ULurl{http://foo.bar/%12%34}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here a adaption of my solution for [Url with fragments in bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12486/url-with-fragments-in-bold/12496#12496). The result it look nice to me. However the URL isn't a hyperlink anymore, i.e. I can't click on it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%% works with `url` only as well:
%\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ulined}{}%
\DeclareUrlCommand{\bulurl}{\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily\color{blue}\ulined}}

\begin{document}

\bulurl{http://www.example.com/blue%^&&*}

\url{http://www.example.com/blue%^&&*}  % for comparision

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

my solution to this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul,lipsum}
\newcommand{\myul}[2][black]{\setulcolor{#1}\ul{#2}\setulcolor{black}}

\begin{document}
\section{To See}\label{tosee}
hello refer ~\ref{tosee}
\href{www.google.com}{\color{blue} \myul[blue] {GOOGLE}}
\end{document}
```