# Custom switches (such as for underlining)

Tags: macros, text-decorations

Some packages (ntheorem for example) take only text switches as arguments that can be used in the form `{\switch text}`, for example `\bfseries`. If I now want to have a suitable command for underlining, the `\underline` command does not work, as it requires the argument explicitly using parentheses.

To make this clearer, I would like to convert something like

```
\underline{lorem ipsum}
```

to the form

```
{\ulswitch lorem ipsum}
```

Comment: The `latex-project` tag is really just about the develop project of LaTeX. You don't need to tag a question for LaTeX, that's the default here.

Comment: AFAIK, you should not use `\underline` for text, because it is only intended for math. Use `\uline` from `ulem` as I show in my answer or the corresponding macro from `soul`.

Comment: I'm using `ulem`, but I thought `\underline` would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ulem` package to define such formatting macros. The section  2 *Defining new commands* in the manual.

Basically you can turn a `\textsomething{<content>}` macro into a `{\switch <content>}` macro using `\useunder{\textsomething}{\switch}{}`. For underlying 
this can be done using `\useunder{\uline}{\ulined}{}` where `\uline{<content>}` is provided by `ulem` and `\ulined` is made a switch-version of it.
See my answer to [I cannot get a (properly) underlined hyperlink in blue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23208/i-cannot-get-a-properly-underlined-hyperlink-in-blue/23211#23211) where I'm using it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ulined}{}

\begin{document}

before 
{\ulined Some underlined text}
after

\end{document}
```

You should load it with the `normalem` option to keep `\emph` as normal. There is also the `soul` package (Strike-Out, UnderLine) which might do the same.