# Is there an equivalent of \bf for \underline{}?

Tags: underline

We can use `$\bf 10$` for obtaining a bold 10. Of course, this is equivalent to `$\mathbf{10}$`. Is there an equivalent of `\bf` in math environment for `\underline{}`?

I would need something like `$\ul 10$` for a code where I can not use brackets. Concretely, I want to use the code of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33967/highlighting-extremal-values-in-table) with underline instead of bold.
Thanks!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38834/custom-switches-such-as-for-underlining

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I have tried that answer but it does not work inside a math environment ( $\ulined 10$ prints nothing).

Comment: Ah, right, didn't consider that, sorry.

Comment: No, underlining requires braces. On the other hand, `\bf` has been obsolete and deprecated for more than twenty (!) years; the correct markup is `$\mathbf{10}$`.

Comment: Given your comment on the (now-deleted) answer, is your actual question "how can I make a cell in a table generated by `pgfplotstable` underlined?"

Comment: Not really. I want to use `pgfplotstable` like in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33967/highlighting-extremal-values-in-table) but with underline instead of bold.

Comment: Well, that's almost the same thing, only there the cell is identified automatically. Anyways, probably wouldn't have hurt to mention the context in the question as well, though I can't say if it would increase the chance of an answer. Well, @egreg sort of answered already. (Note also that I wasn't notified of your latest comment because you didn't write `@TorbjørnT.` in it, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019)