# How to underline links with pandoc?

Tags: beamer, links, pandoc

Is there any way to underline links with pandoc?

```
[Geogebra](http://google.com)
```

I get this

[image]

but I prefer `__Geogebra__` (`__` means underline)

Comment: Since `pandoc` is creating a `beamer` presentation which uses `hyperref`, you just need to pass the appropriate setup for `hyperref` to `pandoc`.  See [Underlined links with hyperref possible?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47713) for the `hyperref` solution.

Comment: In my case, beamer don't load hyperref: `pandoc -D beamer | grep hyperr` gives me: `% avoid problems with \sout in headers with hyperref:`. But else `latex` templates gives me `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the results of grep

Comment: `beamer` loads `hyperref` itself, so you don't see it in the output of `pandoc -D` but it's definitely loaded.

Comment: So, where does it load the `hyperref` package? How can I modify it?

Comment: Is there a solution for other output documents: like context or html?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following document, when converted with `pandoc` generated underlined links in the resultant PDF. However, as noted in the comments to the linked question here [Underlined links with hyperref possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47713) not all viewers can display the underlined links properly. On my machine (a Mac) only Adobe Reader displays the underlining correctly; both Skim and Preview show a box around the link instead of underlining.

**Markdown document**

```
  ---
  header-includes:
    - \hypersetup{colorlinks=false,
              allbordercolors={0 0 0},
              pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}
  ---
  
  ## A frame title
  
  * A list
  * A list
  * [A list with a link](http://tex.stackexchange.com)
```

**Output PDF (Acrobat)**

[image: Acrobat Reader image of output]

Comment: I want to include this code in my beamer template which I get from `pandoc -D beamer`. How can I include in my beamer template if beamer templates does not include `usepackage{hyperref}`? I want permanent solution

Comment: Just add them as you would any other LaTeX code to the template. Since `beamer` loads `hyperref` your `beamer` template will "understand" the `\hypersetup` command as it does in this document.

Comment: I wanted to underline links in a straight Markdown to PDF pandoc conversion, and including this header worked.