# Passing options to hyperref via Beamer from Pandoc

Tags: beamer, hyperref, pandoc, package-options

If I were writing LaTeX code directly, I could pass options to `hyperref` via `beamer`:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,hyperref={colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue}]{beamer}
```

but I'm not using LaTeX directly; I am using Pandoc instead. I have the option in Pandoc to include a header TeX file, but it is unclear to me how I could change the options passed to Beamer, since the `beamer` package is not loaded by any of my hand-written lines of header code; instead, it is loaded by code generated by Pandoc itself.

I have tried to use `PassOptionsToPackage` (both to `beamer` or `hyperref` directly) but it doesn't seem to take.

How can I set `hyperref` options via `beamer`, when using Pandoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319463/2113), it turns out `hyperref` has a command for setting its options after the package is loaded. Using `hypersetup` I was able to get it working by putting the following in my header `.tex` file:

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue}
```