# underline with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, links

I try to underline my links. So far, I tried to use the solution in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/underlined-links-with-hyperref-possible) but it doesn't seem to work. I also try with \underline inside the \href but the result isn't great. Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   citecolor=black, 
   urlcolor=blue,
   allbordercolors={0 0 0},
   pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}]{hyperref},
}


\begin{document}
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/underlined-links-with-hyperref-possible}{Underlined links with hyperref possible?} \lipsum[1]
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/underlined-links-with-hyperref-possible}{\underline{Underlined links with hyperref possible?}} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I would like to have something like that :

[image]

Is there an easy solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pdfborderstyle doesn't work for two reasons:

- You moved the settings into \hypersetup but didn't remove the `{hyperref}`. If you look in the log you find a warning about it:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Invalid value `{/S/U/W 1}]{hyperref}'
(hyperref)                for option `pdfborderstyle'.
```

- hyperref is the opinion that coloring a link and adding a border is too much. So as soon as you use the `colorlinks` option it will disable the border at begin document. If you really want both you have to reset the border later.

This here works if you have a pdf viewer which supports this border style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{%
 \hypersetup{
   urlcolor=blue,
   urlbordercolor=blue,
   pdfborder={1 1 1},
   pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}   
}}


\begin{document}
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/underlined-links-with-hyperref-possible}{Underlined links with hyperref possible?} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]