# Default value of hyperref's pdfborderstyle setting

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink, default

I have a document where I want to use underlined PDF hyperlinks for the most part, but in one certain part, I need boxed PDF hyperlinks again.

I know that `\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}` [causes the underlining](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/underlined-links-with-hyperref-possible), and that `\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={}}` makes all PDF hyperlinks invisible. But how do I revert to the default boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\hypersetup{pdfborderstyle={/W 1}}` from the point after which you want to have the default boxed PDF hyperlinks. The `W` stands for `width`.