# How to color and underline links on beamer slides?

Tags: beamer, hyperref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot get a (properly) underlined hyperlink in blue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23208/i-cannot-get-a-properly-underlined-hyperlink-in-blue)

I would like to color my web links to cyan and underline them. The color of links used by the beamer should not change.

At the bottom my minimal example. It has following problems:

1. beamer links are colored red (?!)
2. my web link is not underlined

Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=cyan,linkbordercolor=red,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}

\begin{document}

\frame{
  \tableofcontents
}

\section{Section1}

\frame{

\frametitle{Frame1}

\href{http://www.google.com}{My underlined and cyan link to Google}

}

\section{Section2}

\frame{

\frametitle{Frame2}

}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What's package `default`? Commenting out it, hyperlink is not underlined but cyan.

Comment: I think this answer your question: [i-cannot-get-a-properly-underlined-hyperlink-in-blue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23208/i-cannot-get-a-properly-underlined-hyperlink-in-blue)